# SQL Server group by week query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see my query below and the results

```
(SELECT count(*) as Count, p.regionid, a.territory,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 8 THEN '1' 
  ELSE CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 15 then '2' 
    ELSE CASE WHEN  DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 22 then '3' 
      ELSE CASE WHEN  DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 29 then '4'     
       ELSE '5'   
      END
    END
  END
END as WeekNumber 
from pros p 
inner join
GTS_Account a 
on a.locationGTSNo = p.BillToCustNo
  where a.account like '%abc%' and
  p.prodate between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-28' 
group by p.ProDate,p.regionid,a.territory)
```

Results

```
╔═══════╦══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ Count ║ regionid ║ territory ║ WeekNumber ║
╠═══════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║     3 ║ LTL      ║         2 ║          1 ║
║    23 ║ RDFS     ║         2 ║          1 ║
║    10 ║ VOLUME   ║         2 ║          1 ║
║    22 ║ RDFS     ║         2 ║          1 ║
║    10 ║ VOLUME   ║         2 ║          1 ║
║     1 ║ EXP      ║         2 ║          2 ║
║     3 ║ LTL      ║         2 ║          2 ║
║    25 ║ RDFS     ║         2 ║          2 ║
║    11 ║ VOLUME   ║         2 ║          2 ║
║     1 ║ BRK      ║         2 ║          2 ║
║     6 ║ VOLUME   ║         2 ║          2 ║
║     1 ║ BRK      ║         2 ║          3 ║
║     4 ║ EXP      ║         2 ║          3 ║
║     1 ║ LTL      ║         2 ║          3 ║
║    20 ║ RDFS     ║         2 ║          3 ║
║     4 ║ EXP      ║         2 ║          4 ║
║     4 ║ LTL      ║         2 ║          4 ║
║    30 ║ RDFS     ║         2 ║          4 ║
║    15 ║ VOLUME   ║         2 ║          4 ║
╚═══════╩══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

This shows the data for each day in the week, I just want it to show the total for each region/per week not per day. Thanks

3-13-14
I would like to show the Month and Year column for this data, please the query below, it should show only one row for each region/week.

```
SELECT convert(nvarchar,DATEPART(YYYY,p.prodate))  + ' ' +
CASE WHEN DATEPART(month,p.prodate) = 1 THEN 'JAN' 
    WHEN DATEPART(month,p.prodate) = 2 THEN 'FEB' 
    WHEN DATEPART(month,p.prodate) = 3 THEN 'MAR' 
    WHEN DATEPART(month,p.prodate) = 4 THEN 'APR' 
    WHEN DATEPART(month,p.prodate) = 5 THEN 'MAY' 
    WHEN DATEPART(month,p.prodate) = 6 THEN 'JUN' 
    WHEN DATEPART(month,p.prodate) = 7 THEN 'JUL' 
    WHEN DATEPART(month,p.prodate) = 8 THEN 'AUG' 
    WHEN DATEPART(month,p.prodate) = 9 THEN 'SEP' 
    WHEN DATEPART(month,p.prodate) = 10 THEN 'OCT' 
    WHEN DATEPART(month,p.prodate) = 11 THEN 'NOV' 
    WHEN DATEPART(month,p.prodate) = 12 THEN 'DEC' 
    ELSE '6'
    END AS MONTHnAME,
count(*) as Count, p.regionid, 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 8 THEN '1' --+ ' ' +convert(nvarchar,DATEPART(mm,p.prodate))
     WHEN DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 15 then '2' --+ ' ' +convert(nvarchar,DATEPART(mm,p.prodate))
    WHEN  DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 22 then '3' --+ ' ' +convert(nvarchar,DATEPART(mm,p.prodate))
    WHEN  DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 29 then '4'  --+ ' ' +convert(nvarchar,DATEPART(mm,p.prodate))   
    ELSE '5' + ' ' +convert(nvarchar,DATEPART(mm,p.prodate)) 
END as WeekNumber,a.territory,'rrts' from pros p inner join GTS_Account a on a.locationGTSNo = p.BillToCustNo
  where a.account like '%rrts%' and
  p.prodate between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-28' group by 
  CASE 
            WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 8 THEN '1' 
            WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 15 THEN '2' 
            WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 22 THEN '3' 
            WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 29 THEN '4' 
            ELSE '5' 
          END
  ,p.prodate,a.territory, p.regionid
  order by p.regionid, weeknumber
```

MONTHnAME   Count   regionid    WeekNumber  territory   (No column name)
2014 FEB    1   BRK     1   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    1   BRK     2   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    1   BRK     2   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    1   BRK     3   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    2   BRK     4   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    1   BRK     4   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    1   DED     3   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    3   EXP     1   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    1   EXP     1   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    2   EXP     1   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    3   EXP     1   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    2   EXP     1   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    1   EXP     2   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    1   EXP     2   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    2   EXP     2   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    1   EXP     2   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    4   EXP     3   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    1   EXP     3   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    6   EXP     3   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    3   EXP     3   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    7   EXP     3   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    1   EXP     4   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    4   EXP     4   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    2   EXP     4   0002    rrts
2014 FEB    3   EXP     4   0002    rrts

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This shows the data for each day in the week, I just want it to show the total for each region/per week not per day.  Thanks.

Comment: (SELECT count(*) as Count, p.regionid, a.territory,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 8 THEN '1' 
  ELSE CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 15 then '2' 
    ELSE CASE WHEN  DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 22 then '3' 
      ELSE CASE WHEN  DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 29 then '4'     
        ELSE '5'
      END
    END
  END
END as WeekNumber from pros p inner join GTS_Account a on a.locationGTSNo = p.BillToCustNo
  where a.account like '%rrts%' and
  p.prodate between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-28' group by p.ProDate,p.regionid,a.territory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to group by the same thing you're selecting instead of `p.prodate`

Also you don't need the nested case statments just multiple WHENs

```
SELECT Count(*) AS Count, 
       p.regionid, 
       a.territory, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 8 THEN '1' 
         WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 15 THEN '2' 
         WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 22 THEN '3' 
         WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 29 THEN '4' 
         ELSE '5' 
       END      AS WeekNumber 
FROM   pros p 
       INNER JOIN gts_account a 
               ON a.locationgtsno = p.billtocustno 
WHERE  a.account LIKE '%abc%' 
       AND p.prodate BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-28' 
GROUP  BY CASE 
            WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 8 THEN '1' 
            WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 15 THEN '2' 
            WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 22 THEN '3' 
            WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 29 THEN '4' 
            ELSE '5' 
          END, 
          p.regionid, 
          a.territory
```

If your case statement is nasty enough you can also use a with clause to make it a little cleaner

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT 
                p.regionid, 
                a.territory, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 8 THEN '1' 
                  WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 15 THEN '2' 
                  WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 22 THEN '3' 
                  WHEN Datepart(day, p.prodate) < 29 THEN '4' 
                  ELSE '5' 
                END AS WeekNumber 
         FROM   pros p 
                INNER JOIN gts_account a 
                        ON a.locationgtsno = p.billtocustno 
         WHERE  a.account LIKE '%abc%' 
                AND p.prodate BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-28') 
SELECT Count(*) As Count,  
       regionid, 
       territory, 
       weeknumber 
FROM   cte 
GROUP  BY weeknumber, 
          regionid, 
          territory
```

Comment: I would like to show the month and year too, please see the new query above. I am not getting the results I desire.

Comment: Is it possible to show the weeks as columns? I would like to dynmically create as many columns as the number of weeks in the date range and show the data.

Comment: You can show weeks instead of day. You'd need to use week instead of day in the datepart function. If you want to do it dynamically you'd need to first find out what weeks are present and then call sp_executeSQL. [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759531/)

Comment: Here is how my data looks

Comment: Shipment Region WeekNumber territory AccountName
3 BRK    Week 1  April  2014 2 rrts
1 BRK    Week 1  February  2014 2 rrts
2 BRK    Week 1  January  2014 2 rrts
1 BRK    Week 1  March  2014 2 rrts
2 BRK    Week 2  April  2014 2 rrts
2 BRK    Week 2  February  2014 2 rrts
5 BRK    Week 2  January  2014 2 rrts
3 BRK    Week 2  March  2014 2 rrts

Comment: I want to show this data horizontally instead of vertically. So, there should be only one row per region. Each row has region and each week as a column in the date range specified. The week number does not have the exact week number in the month but just week1..week2 etc.  Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you that you try adapting the Example I linked to, or you can ask a new question so that I'm not the only one looking at it