# sql server create columns dynamically

Tags: sql

I would like to have only one row per region with week columns generated dynamically between a given date range. Here is my current output.

```
Shipment    Region  WeekNumber  territory   AccountName
1   BRK     Week 1  March  2014 0002    RRTS
3   BRK     Week 2  March  2014 0002    RRTS
1   BRK     Week 3  March  2014 0002    RRTS
1   BRK     Week 5  March  2014 0002    RRTS
1   DED     Week 3  March  2014 0002    RRTS
14  EXP     Week 1  March  2014 0002    RRTS
25  EXP     Week 2  March  2014 0002    RRTS
15  EXP     Week 3  March  2014 0002    RRTS
20  EXP     Week 4  March  2014 0002    RRTS
3   EXP     Week 5  March  2014 0002    RRTS
14  LTL     Week 1  March  2014 0002    RRTS
19  LTL     Week 2  March  2014 0002    RRTS
```

Query

```
SELECT 
count(*) as Count, p.regionid, 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 8 THEN CAST('Week 1  ' AS VARCHAR(20)) + DATENAME(MONTH, p.prodate) + CAST('  ' AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(YEAR(p.prodate) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
--convert(nvarchar,DATEPART(month,p.prodate))
     WHEN DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 15 then CAST('Week 2  ' AS VARCHAR(20)) + DATENAME(MONTH, p.prodate) + CAST('  ' AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(YEAR(p.prodate) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
     --+ CAST(YEAR(p.prodate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + DATENAME(MONTH, p.prodate)
    WHEN  DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 22 then CAST('Week 3  ' AS VARCHAR(20)) + DATENAME(MONTH, p.prodate) + CAST('  ' AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(YEAR(p.prodate) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
    WHEN  DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 29 then CAST('Week 4  ' AS VARCHAR(20)) + DATENAME(MONTH, p.prodate) + CAST('  ' AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(YEAR(p.prodate) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
    ELSE CAST('Week 5  ' AS VARCHAR(20))+ DATENAME(MONTH, p.prodate) + CAST('  ' AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(YEAR(p.prodate) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
END as WeekNumber,a.territory,'rrts' from pros p inner join GTS_Account a on a.locationGTSNo = p.BillToCustNo
  where a.account like '%rrts%' and
  p.prodate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-02-28' group by 
  CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 8 THEN CAST('Week 1  ' AS VARCHAR(20)) + DATENAME(MONTH, p.prodate) + CAST('  ' AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(YEAR(p.prodate) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
     WHEN DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 15 then CAST('Week 2  ' AS VARCHAR(20)) + DATENAME(MONTH, p.prodate) + CAST('  ' AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(YEAR(p.prodate) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
    WHEN  DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 22 then CAST('Week 3  ' AS VARCHAR(20)) + DATENAME(MONTH, p.prodate) + CAST('  ' AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(YEAR(p.prodate) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
    WHEN  DATEPART(day,p.prodate) < 29 then CAST('Week 4  ' AS VARCHAR(20)) + DATENAME(MONTH, p.prodate) + CAST('  ' AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(YEAR(p.prodate) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
    ELSE CAST('Week 5  ' AS VARCHAR(20)) + DATENAME(MONTH, p.prodate) + CAST('  ' AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(YEAR(p.prodate) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
END

  ,a.territory, p.regionid
  order by p.regionid, weeknumber
```

Desired output is:

```
Region  Territory   Week1   Week2   Week3   Week4   Week5   Week6
BRK            2      4     6       8       10      5       4
DED            2      7     5       4       7       7       2
EXP            2      1     1       2       4       5       6
```

Thanks!
I am using sql server 2008

Comment: Can you show your desired output as well as the query you're using?

Comment: Your database engine is relevent and you didn't provide it.

Comment: You can use **PIVOT** for this...

Comment: I have tried pivot from some examples on the web but couldn't figure out how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like sql server which means pivot is the way to go.  I suggest starting with something simpler and work your way up.

Comment: What is your table structure? GTS_Account is where all of the orders are stored is that correct? the BRK/DED/EXP are customer numbers? Seems like two outer apply imbricated is what you need initial From should be looking at the table containing all of your regions, first outer apply joining on territory and an imbricated outer apply to the table having the week #.

Comment: Pros are where the orders are stored and gts_account is where all the account info for each client is stored. Week numbers aren't stored anywhere, want to create them dynamically based on date range. Each customer is assigned a region, BRK is one of the regions.

Comment: Please see the first query in the question in this link, I am fine if the week rows in that are converted to columns.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356147/sql-server-group-by-week-query

Comment: I get this error if I use pivot. "You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE." Is there any other way?

Comment: I will not be able to use pivot since our compatibility is set to Sql server 2000 for the sake of some older applications.