# How do I use row data as columns, with variable row data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in database like :

[image]

And I want the data Output like :

[image]

FeeName Column value is not fixed i.e. another type of fee can be there too.

Kindly help to resolve it.

Looking for your valuable solutions.

Thanks...

Comment: Search SO or the web for "pivot table'.

Comment: Also, if you have to twist your data like this to get the answer you want, your data structures probably aren't correct for your requirements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server PIVOT examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)

Comment: @Ninjapig, I don't think this is a duplicate of that, as the columns are well-defined in the example you link. Supriya states that her columns are dynamic.

Comment: Friend pls search for dynamic PIVOT, that is what u want.

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759531/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server take a look at answer which is marked useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Turophile says, this data format indicates a problem in your data design.

Still, if you need to do this, here's how i would do it:

(note I created a temp table, and populated it in the example. You already have the table and the data, but I needed something for testing)

```
Create table #feeSchedule
(
    FeeId int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    Description nvarchar(255) not null,
    FeeAmount money not null,
    FeeName nvarchar(50) not null
)
go

insert into #feeSchedule values('Nursery', 5000, 'Admission Fee')
insert into #feeSchedule values('Nursery', 1000, 'Tuition Fee')
insert into #feeSchedule values('Nursery', 100, 'Late Fee')
insert into #feeSchedule values('Nursery', 0, 'Exam Fee')
insert into #feeSchedule values('Play Group', 5000, 'Admission Fee')
insert into #feeSchedule values('Play Group', 2500, 'Tuition Fee')
insert into #feeSchedule values('Play Group', 100, 'Late Fee')
insert into #feeSchedule values('Play Group', 0, 'Exam Fee')


DECLARE @columnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @columnHeaders = 
  COALESCE( 
    @columnHeaders + ',[' + cast(FeeName as varchar) + ']',
    '[' + cast(FeeName as varchar)+ ']'
  )
FROM (select distinct FeeName from #feeSchedule) as fs

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = N'
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      fs.Description,
      fs.FeeName,
      fs.FeeAmount
    FROM #feeSchedule fs
  ) AS PivotData
  PIVOT (
    SUM(FeeAmount)
    FOR FeeName IN (
      ' + @columnHeaders + '
    )
  ) AS PivotTable
'

exec sp_ExecuteSql @sql

go
drop table #feeSchedule
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 
    Description(invoiceDate) as [year],FeeAmount, 
    InvoiceAmount as Amount 
FROM TableName
) as s
PIVOT
(
SUM(Amount)
FOR [month] IN (Admission Fee, Tution Fee, Exam Fee, Late Fee)
)AS pivot
```